# What do the circles' color in gource mean?

Tags: gource

When we launch gource in software version control (e.g. in local git repository) while generating video of project evolution, the circles change their color. I suppose they indicate some state. But what state exactly do they indicate of?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think it indicates the file type, not a state...

If the parameter "--key" is used, a brief list of type/color is showed in the screen.

[image: Example from Linux kernel video]

[Documentation from Gource](https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource/wiki/Controls#legend--file-extension-key)

Comment: It seems that you are right, that's why I voted up. But can you write your answer in more details with some proofs or documentations if possible?

Comment: I launched gource with --key as you said, but the color in the brief list doesn't change even when circles color changed. One more thing from time to time java files color changed from yellow to green and at the end it turned to dark blue. I think the colors show oldness of the files.

Comment: I was looking around in code source, and in the "file.cpp" https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource/blob/master/src/file.cpp, we can see a function called **colorize**, where the color is set by the extension... but i only have spent few minutes in my research.